# Is there a published adventure in any D&D edition where the dungeon is a construct?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification, constructs

Does anyone know if a campaign exists that takes the PCs through a dungeon, where they are looking for a construct, only to realize at the end that the dungeon itself *is* the construct?

I am asking about any edition, from AD&D until present, no just material published by WoTC.

I was writing a dungeon with this theme, but I want make sure I wasn't copying something that was already published.

Comment: There's a meta that discusses whether "does it exist" questions are game-recs or not but it didn't get a lot of traction, feel free and chip in here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6052/are-does-this-type-of-product-exist-questions-acceptable

Answer (score 20):

## Yes, plenty.

There are plenty of dungeons that are themselves constructs or located within constructs.

For example, the Doomgrinder from the eponymous Greyhawk module is a dungeon in an activated war machine.  But there's also adventures in human-type colossi (e.g. the BECMI D&D module CM4 Earthshaker!), living dungeons, and so on.  If your bar for writing an adventure is "there's no other adventure like this ever" then you should largely give up now. In 40+ years of D&D someone's had the exact same "cool out-of-the-box" adventure idea that you have at some point.

Luckily that's not the bar anyone uses.  If it's a good adventure and not too identical to any adventure in the last couple years, especially not in the same edition, then you're fine.

Comment: This is answering the question in the bold title and is perfectly correct (+1). I could add Lolth's giant mechanical spider in Q1 as another example. But in the body of the post, Yonaton asks a more specific question: is there an adventure where the PCs are seeking a construct only to find out at the end that the dungeon was the construct? I think this disqualifies your examples and I'm not sure the answer to this question is Yes. How is it usually handled when the title question doesn't really match the question in the post?